# Voltage drop from PCB ground plane to motor driver

Tags: voltage, pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, surface-mount

***Note: Feedback has been addressed and the circuit has been updated, however the same behaviour still applies***

I'm new to creating circuits but have designed a PCB and made it with Eagle, however, the BD6210F that I'm using doesn't want to allow me to run the motor due to the voltage only being input at 2.5v.

According to [the datasheet for the BD6210F](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/motor/dc/bd621x-e.pdf), there are two important steps to getting this device to work:

1. Choose the operating mode (Page 10 attached at bottom has a table of
   choice of which I chose b and c)
2. Based on B, C I need to have VREF Connected to VCC

To do this with Arduino I'm doing the following with an ESP32:

```
  if (is_open) {
    digitalWrite(LEFT_PIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RIGHT_PIN, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LEFT_PIN, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RIGHT_PIN, LOW);
  }
```

I've used a multimeter to confirm that 3.3v is going into RIN and low voltage is being applied to FIN, and the reverse given either situation, however, the motor is only receiving 2.5v of power due to the source voltage (VCC) being 2.5v.

I've isolated this down to one section of the board which is the ground plane since when I measure any voltage with it grounded to that there's a drop of 0.8v, so my 5v input measures 4.2v while my 3.3v input measures 2.5v even though if I ground to the battery source directly it measures 3.3v and 5v respectively.  I'm not sure why this happens though or what I need to do to stop this from happening, any advice or pointers would be great since I'm stumped!

### References

[image: Operating Modes]

[image: Full Schematic]

[image: PCB Schematic]

## Update After Modification Edit

After redoing the schematic to use enable and printing out a new circuit board, I realized the voltage drop only occurs with batteries and is still present even with the extra capacitors. On top of that I've discovered more of its behavior:
Measuring the voltage to the voltage regulator this is what I'm given:

1. With no battery connected 0v (obviously right?!)
2. With battery connected the voltage jumps to 3.6 and then immediately starts dropping
3. Voltage hits 2.5v and stops dropping
4. Disconnecting the battery and there is now ~0.7v in the circuit that begins discharging slowly till it reaches 0

I'm not sure why this would happen or why it's acting as a battery storage!

#### New Schematic

[image: schematic new]
[image]

Comment: Can I ask what the transistor is meant to accomplish, if that is not saturated, the ground of the chip will rise.

Comment: I honestly wasn't too sure about this one @Reroute, but I figured it would be a good way to cut power to the motor driver, please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm still learning! It's a very low power application and spends most of the time in deep sleep

Comment: That would be my main suspicion for now, try shorting out collector to emitter and see if your problem goes away, the more modern approach would be to use a logic level N-channel mosfet with a low on resistance, as they can switch amps without power being consumed from the micro controller.

Comment: Hmm yeah I did this and it seems to work now, I'm trying to get it to reproduce again so i can confirm, do you have a favorite package for the mosfet you can recommend? I'll have to switch out the package

Comment: Plenty of mosfets in Sot23, so you can likely find one that can be a drop in replacment

Comment: Are you planning to put the ESP32 in sleep mode?

Comment: @vtolentino yes for very long periods of time, it's only on basically when the touch sensor is activated which is probably every 6 hours sometimes not for 12 - 24h

Comment: @Reroute Awesome, so I just use a N-channel mosfet and it'll just work? Why does that make a difference (curious for learning sake)?

Comment: The BJT Transistor has to be "saturated" with a current to its base to have a low voltage between emitter and collector, the 1K resistor from your micro's output may not be low enough to keep it saturated when you have the load of a motor passing ground current, however a mosfet only needs a voltage to be "saturated", and while saturated will be very close to the on resistance spec of the mosfet which may be say 0.05 ohms, (this is why it needs to be logic level, so that saturation voltage is low)

Comment: Ahh ok thanks so much for this explanation @Reroute, mosfets and transistors are a tricky one for me still because while I get what they do and semi understand how they work, it's not 100% comprehensive yet for me

Comment: @Reroute how do you choose N-Channel mosfets, do you have any resources you could point me at? I was looking at [digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/micro-commercial-co/2SK3018-TP/2SK3018-TPMSCT-ND/6616131) for one but they have such high amperage

Comment: High amperage is not an issue. It just means it wont break until that limit. So a higher number is not an issue. Main parameters. Rds on should be low for power loads. If you want your ground to not shift by more than a few 10s of mV. Think of it like a resistance in series with a light switch. Next up gate drive voltage. If you only have 3.3V from ground. Then the mosfet you choose needs a voltage equal to or lower than that to saturate. On other projects the  drain to source voltage should be higher than what it is likely to see. The other stuff is mainly for switching at high frequency

Comment: Oh awesome, it looks like the one I choose is all within those parameters!! Thanks a bunch for the explanation as well. (If you were to make this an answer I would happily select it)

Comment: I think I got the wrong one, the voltage stopped running on any of the pins connected to it or the motor driver @Reroute, remind me to read the spec sheets better!!

Comment: see if the pinout is different, you may just need to rotate or flip the part,

Comment: It actually was the same as far as I could tell. I think I'm going to have to suck it up and use the standby mode, unless I did buy the wrong mosfet, but I think I got it right!

Comment: Even after your edit it is substantially unclear what you are asking about.  **You need to clearly show what circuit voltage you are measuring**.

Comment: Hey Chris, I actually did specify I'm measuring the voltage to the voltage regulator, maybe I'm not on the same page for what to specify, I'm still new to this sorry

Comment: What is the voltage and current rating of this motor (datasheet or measurment)?. This LDO can deliver up to 250mA, and this current is shared by both the uC and the motor, which might be too low.

Comment: Looks like it's max is 450mA, which is way to high for 250! My question with this though would be why does this problem only show up on battery power!! If usb or bench powered this problem doesn't exist. It's very confusing! I'm rebuilding another version where the vin goes straight to the motor driver and another path goes straight to the LDO, if that works it's for sure this problem! Another thing I found was there's a dropout voltage of max 0.6v and I'm using a 3.6v source for a 3.3v LDO, so I'm not sure if that may be causing issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the battery, I'm not sure how to measure max draw but 1/2 AA batteries aren't capable of providing 200ma of power.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of @Reroute's comment, this voltage offset is probably due to the non-zero collector-to-emitter voltage of your bipolar transistor. If the intention was to cut the power of the motor when it is not being used, you could have done it by setting the motor in Stand-by mode.

According to the datasheet, once in stand by mode, the internal circuitry is turned off and the current consumption drops from \$1.5mA\$ tp \$10\mu A\$. Setting the motor in stand-by mode requires only that you pull the pins \$F_{IN}\$ and \$R_{IN}\$ low.

[image: table]

Comment: Is 10 going to be less than with it cut off with a transistor though? I guess I'm unaware of if transistors take up amperage to be honest. The ESP32 on deep sleep takes up around 10 itself and I wanted to keep it as low as possible

Comment: Probably not, a BJT BC548 has a cut-off current of 15nA and a logic MOSFET would be around the same range.

Comment: Good to know, I had a feeling transistor cut off would be more efficient than standby which is why I ended up going that route, I don't really understand how a lot of components work with amperage yet, still lots to learn!

Comment: If the quiescent current during sleep mode of your board is much larger than \$10 \mu A\$, meaning that the latter is almost negligible, you should consider using the stand-by function of the motor driver.

Comment: When it's sleeping it only will be powering the esp32 plus the transistor/mosfet so it should be around 10 only!

Comment: I've rebuilt it to use enable vs the mosfet and it still doesn't work. Some very interesting behaviour is that the voltage goes to the same as the battery, then procedes to start dropping. Upon removing the battery there's still residual voltage in the device seemingly whatever was dropped is stored and is discharged after the battery is disconnected. This is interesting in itself but why does this happen and how do I stop it!? This doesn't happen using A USB to power it just the battery

Comment: Can you update your question with your new schematic and clearly indicate the voltage you are referring to?

Comment: I've updated the question with the new schematic and added that I'm referring to the input voltage that goes to the regulator!!

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem causes by BJT due to v_ce, if you really want to do that, use logic level fet instead.
2. If you you vcc from micro controller to power motor , it will lead to power problem like voltage drop or voltage spike. The effect if his mcu can be reset due to brownout or just broke by high voltage spike

Comment: VCC does split off to microcontroller and motor driver. I actually have seen resets so I'm assuming this is why, how can I fix this? Also what is v_ce (sorry I'm a newb)?

Comment: Voltage across collector and emitter of BJT. when you use bjt as switch it have voltage drop across it.

Comment: For mcu reset it just some time motor draw to much current and vcc is drop for sometime cause mcu toreset.

Comment: We must have proper power supply for motor and add bypass capacitor it help a lot.

Comment: By proper power supply, you mean separate? This isn't possible given the size constraints I'm working with unfortunately I'll try and use a bypass capacitor closer to the motor

Comment: Not necessary, Just power source that can deliver current it's needed. Also don't forget decoupling cap.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thanks! The power supply should be enough to power the motor because it's a 3v motor so it's not too hefty anyway. Is there anything else I should add in outside a decoupling capacitor and bypass capacitor? I'm on my 3rd version of the pcb and crafting them with my cnc is a huge pain so I'm hoping the 4th is my last!

Comment: Seem like nothing to worry. have a look at this commercial product.
[link](http://doc.switch-science.com/schematic/DB6211F_Module/DB6211F_Module_sch.pdf) 
You need to add big cap (10uF ceramic or film) near H-Bridge ICs.

Comment: Alright, awesome! should I add one for vref as well? I actually thought the capacitor I had  coming from the 3v3 voltage regulator was going to work as the capacitor for the H-bridge IC

Comment: If you have long distance you should have cap. at both end.

Comment: Looks like the resets were actually from me using an integer as opposed to a uint_64 for the deep sleep timer! But if the switch to a mosfet doesn't work I'll give this a shot next, I don't think the distance is that long for the capacitor but maybe it is there's a lot of signals crossing it?

Comment: No one can tell except oscilloscope, haha  let probe it out!

Comment: I'm still waiting on my oscilloscope haha, what should I look for in the measurements if it was crossing?

Comment: just look for voltage spike what operating